# How to change gravity of Navigation Drawer button?

Tags: android, toolbar, right-to-left

I have navigation drawer, and a button on the toolbar that when you click it it opens it and make some kind of nice animation.
I'm trying to move the button from the right side to the left side, but unsuccessfully. 
I tried to change the gravity of it from start to end, but it didn't change it.
It was made by a template of android studio.
Moreover, when I click this Button it crashes me.
when I change the "android:supportsRtl" to false, it changes the side of the button to the left, as I want, but it then changes the side of the drawer as well.
and I also need to supportsRTL, so it's not a good solution.  (I set it to "true" on the manifest)

What is the problem? and How can I get the Navigation Icon on the left side, with the nice animation?
BTH, how can I make the navigation be a little bit smaller(that I can see the toolbar) ?

ScreenShots[image]

[image]

AppBarMain.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

ActivityMain.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your navigation view has `android:layout_gravity="end"`. Did you mean `start`?

Comment: No, I want it to be open from the left side. when I change it to "start" then it opened from the right side. also it's not changing the side of the navigationDrawer Button to the left.   @EugenPechanec

Comment: The point of RTL is to flip everything - navigation menu and button is on the right, overflow icon is on the left etc. Best described in material design docs https://www.google.com/design/spec/usability/bidirectionality.html. Just force RTL on your device and run some of the classic apps like Gmail to see how it's done. If you do it otherwise you'll just confuse the user AND make your job a whole lot harder.

Comment: I want to make my overflow Icon(of the navigation drawer) from on RTL on the left side, and on LTR on the right side. I don't have any intrest in changing all of my app this way. Because I need it RTL @EugenPechanec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a custum view in the toolbar if you want something as custom as having the drawer toggle in the opposite side of the drawer.
Uppon click:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```

And for the toolbar - you can just put the drawer below the toolbar in a vertical `LinearLayout`

Answer (score 1):

In main activity add these lines:

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="anyRtl"
```